# Cannot see an Event in Google Analytics even when I push the datalayer

Tags: .net, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

I am trying to push an ID to Google Analytics and am not seeing it come through. Here is my cshtml code:

```
@{
    string id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
}

<script>
    console.log('about to declare the datalayer');
    var id = '@id';

    console.log('id:' + id);
    dataLayer = [{
        'event': 'getIdentifier',
        'uniqueIdentifier': id
      }];

    console.log('about to push the datalayer');
    var dataLayer = window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    dataLayer.push({
      'event': 'getIdentifier',
      'uniqueIdentifier': id
    });

    console.log('finished pushing the datalayer');
</script>
```

I declare the Google Tag Manager stuff and the above code in the head.

When the page is navigated to, I can see that the Id is created and all the console.logs fire, but nothing comes through to my Google Analytics real time events viewer.

Am I doing something wrong?

Google Tag Manager Script in the head:

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
        <script>
            console.log('about to do GTM2');
            (function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
            new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
            j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
            'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
            })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','[container id]');
        </script>
        <!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

Google Tag Manager Script in the body:

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
        <noscript>
            <iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=[container id]"
                    height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe>
        </noscript>
            <!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
```

Comment: You can only initialize dataLayer **BEFORE** the first script in the head. And if you are placing the code before then you cant push.

Comment: GTM is just the tag manager, so there isn't enough information here to expect be expecting anything in GA. What GA tags did you setup to fire on the GTM event and what does the gtm debugger show about the tags and their contents during this event?

Comment: I actually fired up the GTM Preview and I see it now. I added the tag and Custom Dimension and I'm good.

Answer (score 0):

I now see it in Google Analytics. I wasn't looking in the right place.